# ¿Alguien sabría hacer un algoritmo de forma iterativa (usando while) para la siguiente definición?

Tags: java, bucles, algoritmos, recursión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero hacer un algoritmo iterativo a partir de la definicion que me han dado. Lo tengo hecho con recursión con memoria, lo comparto por si ayuda:

```
public static Integer eje4ConMemoria(Integer d1, Integer d2, Map<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, Integer> memoria) {
    Integer result = null;
    Integer a = d1;
    Integer b = d2;
    Tuple2<Integer, Integer> t = Tuple.create(a, b);
    if (memoria.containsKey(t)) {
        result = memoria.get(t);
    } else if (a < 2 && b < 2) {
        result = a + b * b;
        memoria.put(t, result);
    } else if (a < 2 || b < 2) {
        result = a * a + b;
        memoria.put(t, result);
    } else {
        result = eje4ConMemoria(a / 2, b - 1, memoria) + eje4ConMemoria(a / 3, b - 2, memoria)
                + eje4ConMemoria(a - 2, b / 4, memoria);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Pero, si hiciste lo más dificil

Comment: Encontré un blog que podría ayudarte con tu problema https://www.dokry.com/1318